# how to create a container of shared_ptr to abstract class

Tags: c++, c++14, shared-ptr

I'm trying to create a subject-observers system in C++, like the events system in C#.
the observer class:

```
template <class T>
class Observer {
    int id;
public:
    static int nextId;
    Observer() : id(nextId++) {}
    virtual void handleEvent(const T&) = 0;
    virtual ~Observer();
};
```

the subject class:

```
template<class T>
class Subject {
    set<shared_ptr<Observer<T>>> observers;
public:
    Subject() : observers() {}
    void notify(const T&);
    void addObserver(Observer<T>& );
    void removeObserver(Observer<T>&);
    Subject<T>& operator+=(Observer<T>&);
    Subject<T>& operator-=(Observer<T>&);
    Subject<T>& operator()(const T&);
};
```

the problem is when I try to implement `addObserver` I don't know how to add the reference to the set.

I understand `make_shared<Observer<T>>` is creating a new instance, so when I tried `make_shared<Observer<T>>(observer)` I got an error of trying to create an abstract class :

> error: invalid new-expression of abstract class type ‘Observer’

I tried `shared_ptr<Observer<T>> observerPtr(observer)` and it did not work as well :

> error: no matching function for call to ‘std::shared_ptr >::shared_ptr(Observer&)’

how can I create a `shared_ptr` from a reference of an object derived from an abstract class?

what I'm trying to achieve is make this example work:

```
class TemperatureSensor : public Subject<int> {};

class AirConditioner : public Observer<int> {

    static int nextId;
    int id;

    void onTemperatureChange(int temperature){
        std::cout << "Air Conditioner #" << id << " got a report from TemperatureSensor, reading " << temperature << std::endl;
    }

public:
    AirConditioner() : Observer() {
        id = (++nextId);
    }

    void handleEvent(const int& param) override {
        onTemperatureChange(param);
    }
};
int AirConditioner::nextId = 0;

int main(){
    TemperatureSensor s;
    AirConditioner a,b,c;

    (((s += a) += b) += c);

    s(42);  // Should print:
            // Air Conditioner #1 got a report from TemperatureSensor, reading 42
            // Air Conditioner #2 got a report from TemperatureSensor, reading 42
            // Air Conditioner #3 got a report from TemperatureSensor, reading 42
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and the error message you get (if any)

Comment: The problem is that you need to create a (shared) pointer to the *concrete* class. So you need something like `make_shared<ActualConcreteClass>()`.

Comment: A class template with virtual methods is almost always a design error.

Comment: Consider using Boost.Signals2 instead.

Comment: can u elaborate?

Comment: I don't think the abstract class is actually your problem here. Your problem is unclear ownership. For example in the last code block: Until when should the `TemperatureSensor` object live? Should it live until the end of the function where it is created? Until it is removed from the `observers` set? Why is a raw pointer or `std::unique_ptr` not sufficient? Who is supposed to *own* (maybe shared) the object?

Comment: Please clarify whether you want to save a pointer to a *copy* of the passed object in `observers` or whether you want to save a pointer to the passed object itself. My comments on the question and answer so far were under the impression that you require pointers to the objects themselves, based on a previous, now deleted, question of yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question regarding implementing addObserver, the easiest way to get it work is to store the pointer in the container:

```
template<class T>
class Subject {
    set<Observer<T>*> observers;
public:
    Subject() : observers() {}
    void addObserver(Observer<T>& o) { observers.insert(&o); }
```

Depending on how you wish to manage the life cycle of the observer object, you could use `set<shared_ptr<Observer<T>>>`, but in this case, you should pass the `share_ptr<Observer<T>>` as parameter of `addObserver(shared_ptr<Observer<T>>& o)`. If you have to use `addObserver(Observer<T>&)` interface and you want the "observers" set to co-manage the life cycle of the observer object, you could use std::enable_shared_from_this and make Observer a subclass of std::enable_shared_from_this.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's what I did eventually, I was just about writing the answer.

Answer (score 0):

> how can I create a shared_ptr from a reference of an object derived from an abstract class?

In general, you cannot. A shared pointer to abstract base can only be pointed to concrete instances. You generally cannot know the concrete type through a base reference at compile time.

You should probably change the interface so that the function accepts a shared pointer as argument, instead of a reference.

Comment: can't do... the example is how it used right now and I can't change it.
I can change the subject class if you have any idea how to make the example work

Comment: @GuySadoun Changing the interface of the Subject class is what I suggested you to do.

Comment: @GuySadoun You *must* change the contents of `main` in your example if you want a `shared_ptr` that is to the original object rather than a copy of it. It is impossible to obtain a `shared_ptr` to an automatic variable such as `s`, `a`, `b` and `c`.

Answer (score 0):

***how can I create a shared_ptr from a reference of an object derived from an abstract class?***

> **You cannot create a shared_ptr to an abstract class.**

But you can do something to do the code work.

A possible solution is to define the base class **Observer** ***not abstrastct***, removing the `=0`. Then for ensure you actual pure virtual function to not be called on base class Observer in the a bad way you can throw exception in the implementation of the method of the base class Observer. So that when called on **Observer** class it raises an exception, in the other case ( for example in the **AirConditioner** class) it does its work without raising exception.

Note: *This is a just a workaround for this case, try to re-think your code design for a better implementation*

Answer (score 0):

C# makes it easy to ignore the lifetime of `Observer` in `Subject`, and things will (mostly) be ok. C++ doesn't let you ignore lifetimes.

If a `Subject` should keep all the `Observer`s alive, then you need to pass `std::shared_ptr<Observer>`, not `Observer &`.

If you are sure your `Observer`s always outlive your `Subject`, or can always call `removeObserver` before they die, then you can still pass `Observer &`, and store `std::reference_wrapper<Observer>`.

If all your `Observer`s are owned by `std::shared_ptr`s, but you don't want `Subject` to affect their lifetime, pass and store `std::weak_ptr<Observer>`.